# Is null checking for desktop window handle needed

Tags: null, desktop, handle

In my application I acquire the desktop window handle by the below statement:
HWND hDeskTopWnd = :: GetDesktopWindow();

Is it required to perform null checking for hDeskTopWnd. Will the desktop window be null in any case as long as the desktop exists.Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there is no description of a NULL return value. However, there is also no harm (and probably a lot of good) in putting a check just in case. It costs little and may save a lot.

Comment: I agree with you. But I just want to know will there be any situation in which the desktop handle goes null or invalid.

Comment: *I* don't think so, but others may differ. Also see this post for more useful info - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9222739/2065121